# Linux OS to IOS Device

Tags: linux, ios

I want to put my linux os on my iPad. What do I have to modify on it or can I just plugin a keyboard to it? And the more important question can I even put it on? It is an iso file and works on any VM.

Comment: If you hover over your [ios] tag, you'll see that the Apple SE site is the place where your question will be on-topic.

Comment: Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic (except when they interface with a computer). See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking these questions the answer is "you can't".   iPads are designed to NOT run any other OS's, and any limited success people have on doing this is highly specialised and not main stream.

Your belief that an ISO file will work on any VM is wrong - Linux (and all OS's) are architecture dependent - thus you would need to get a version of Linux which will work with that architecture [ this is probably possible, most likely you need an ARM based distro ].

The bigger problems will be getting VM software for iPad or getting past the bootloader restrictions.

You could, of-coruse, have the illusion of Linux on your ipad by running it on another box and then using a remote client to access the Linux box from your iPad.